# How to extract timestamp for a specific date within a specific period in pandas?

Tags: pandas

I have the following dates.

```
start = '2013-12-03'
end = '2023-07-17'
date = '05-02'
```

I want to get only the dates that match `date` between `start` and `end`.

desired output:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2014-05-02', '2015-05-02', '2016-05-02', '2017-05-02',
               '2018-05-02', '2019-05-02', '2020-05-02', '2021-05-02',
               '2022-05-02', '2023-05-02'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name=0, freq=None)
```

I used the following code.

```
import pandas as pd 
m, d = map(int, date.split('-'))

idx = pd.date_range(start[:5] + '01-01', end[:5] + '12-31', freq='12M') 
pd.Index(idx.to_frame()[0].add(pd.DateOffset(month=m, day=d))[lambda x: x.between(start, end)])
```

Is there a simpler way?

There was a way to use `freq='AS-MAY'`, but it required modification depending on the case when in the same month.

---

i edit @Suraj Shourie answer more simply

```
start_year = pd.to_datetime(start).year

dates = pd.date_range(f'{start_year}-{date}', end, freq=pd.DateOffset(months=12))
dates[dates >= start]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a more straightforward way, but using this you won't get the performance warning your code gives. I tried to make it more generic and use a simple boolean filter instead of the lambda filter:

```
import pandas as pd

start = '2013-12-03'
end = '2023-07-17'
date = '05-02'

start_year = pd.to_datetime(start).year
end_year = pd.to_datetime(end).year

dates = pd.date_range(start=f"{start_year}-{date}", end=f"{end_year}-{date}", freq=pd.DateOffset(months=12))
dates[(dates >= start) & (dates <= end)] # Filter
```

Output:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2014-05-02', '2015-05-02', '2016-05-02', '2017-05-02',
               '2018-05-02', '2019-05-02', '2020-05-02', '2021-05-02',
               '2022-05-02', '2023-05-02'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='<DateOffset: months=12>')
```

Comment: thx. i edit your answer more simply. then your  attempt was  simpler than mine. However, I'll wait and see if there is a direct answer

Answer (score 0):

You can play with start and end datetimes for correct edge cases:

```
start = '2013-12-03'
end = '2023-07-17'
date = '05-02'

s = pd.to_datetime(start) 
e = pd.to_datetime(end)
s1 = pd.to_datetime(f'{s.year}-{date}')
e1 = pd.to_datetime(f'{e.year}-{date}')

out = pd.date_range(f'{s.year + int(s > s1)}-{date}', 
                    f'{e.year - int(e < e1)}-{date}', 
                    freq=pd.DateOffset(months=12))
print (out)
DatetimeIndex(['2014-05-02', '2015-05-02', '2016-05-02', '2017-05-02',
               '2018-05-02', '2019-05-02', '2020-05-02', '2021-05-02',
               '2022-05-02', '2023-05-02'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='<DateOffset: months=12>')
```